# 2 Threads, 1 File

Tags: c#, multithreading, file, stream

Since [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14192699/how-to-read-standard-output-of-my-own-application) can't be solved so easily how can I implement 1 thread that **writes** strings to a file / buffer line by line using `Console.WriteLine()` and another thread that **reads** those strings from the same file / buffer also line by line ? I guess I need to:

- redirect Console to file / buffer
- read file / buffer thread save, when a line is written it must be read by the other thread
- make that asynchronous (no `ReadToEnd()`, it must be **live**)

Comment: it's a little smelly requirement: could you describe what you are trying to achieve in first instance?

Comment: Soner, I recommend you to take a look to some concurrency concepts and maybe you will reach your goal by using monitors or semaphores. Cheers.

Comment: I would prefer the buffer version. But the file seems easier. If you know an easy way to avoid file with buffers let me know please. @Soner the text data is not sensitive and the function is simple so I don't care for monitors and semaphores. I just don't want to miss strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to do that with a **buffer** though.

Solution with **file**:

```
    class Program
    {
        private static bool terminated = false;

        private static void listen()
        {
            StreamReader file = new StreamReader(new FileStream("C:/test.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite));
            while (!terminated || !file.EndOfStream)
                if (!file.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string text = file.ReadLine();
                    MessageBox.Show(text); // display it
                }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(new FileStream("C:/test.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read));
            sw.AutoFlush = true;
            Console.SetOut(sw);
            new Thread(new ThreadStart(listen)).Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(250);
                Console.Out.WriteLine("hello world - " + i);
            }
            terminated = true;
        }
    }
```

Works line by line and doesn't miss one.

Answer (score 1):

try [Memory-Mapped files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx) it will allow you to read write to one shared file from multiple threads. As to redirecting console try:

[Console.SetIn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setin.aspx)

[Console.SetOut](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setout.aspx)